# Filtering by storeview retrieves products with no storeview specific data specified

Tags: magento

I'm filtering a collection with a big amount of data. I've 9 different storeviews.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->setStoreId($storeId)->addAttributeToSelect('weight');

    $cnt = 0;
    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {

        $weight = $product->setStoreId($storeId)->getweight();
        echo $product->getsku() . "<br>";
    }
```

The strange thing is that I'm getting all the sku's even of those products who doesn't have any information for the specific selected store view. So it seems that the filter for the storeview doesn't work.
The weight value returned is the value taken from the Default View.
How can I filter in order to have the products with no data specified for a specific storeview excluded from the list ?

Answer (score 0):

Is a little bit slower but I solved filtering this way:

```
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {

    $storeIds = $product->getStoreIds();
    if (in_array($storeId, $storeIds)) {

        // only products present in selected storeview
        $weight = $product->setStoreId($storeId)->getweight();
        echo $product->getsku() . "<br>";
    }
}
```